# Non Site Admins are unable to create sub-sites with templates created by the site admin account

Tags: site-collection, site-template, sub-site

I have created a SharePoint site collection on SharePoint server 2013.
I have create a number of sub sites and for each of those sub sites I have created a template.

The purpose of the templates is to create a site exactly like the site above, same colour, formatting etc.

The templates were created by the site admin, but when a user with 'full access' permissions (not a site admin) tries to create a site using those templates, they get the following error message:

> 'Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you...'

However, they can create sites without using those templates.

The question is, how do I enable these admin users to create sites with these templates?

Comment: are they able to access layouts pages ? like `/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx` or `/_layouts/15/settings.aspx` on the newly created sites ?